# Checking whether a non-hardwired member function exists with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, return-value, overloading, c++11

I want to create proxies for member functions and operators. They must have the same return type and parameters, and must be good for several classes, which are given as template parameters. Even if the class does not have the particular member function or operator, I want it to compile instead of failing with an error, essentially SFINAE. If `X` has a method `f()` and `Y` does not have any method named `f`, I need `Proxy<X>` to have an `f()` as well that calls `X::f()`, and I need `Proxy<Y>` to compile and instantiate without any problems.

Extracting the return type from a known function is no longer a problem, after a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260561/extracting-the-return-type-from-an-overloaded-function). However it fails with an error if there is no such function.

I already know several template metaprogramming tricks to determine whether a given function exists, and enable a certain feature if they do, however, they all work only on hardwired function names instead of arbitrary ones, which severely limits their use in this case since I need the same construct for several functions.

I only need to check whether any function with the given name exists, if there are overloaded variants I do not need to check if a specific one exists, automatic template deduction solves that (or so I hope)

My current code looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class Proxy
{

    //  using my resultof solution
    template <class... Args>
    resultof(T::f, Args...) f (Args... x)
    {
        return x.f(x...);
    }

    //  using another return type extraction solution
    template <class... Args>
    typeof(T::f(std::declval<Args>()...)) f (Args... x)
    {
        return x.f(x...);
    }

    T x;

};
```

Which should compile even if T does not have any function named f. Unfortunately both version fail with an error.

The implementation of resultof being

```
#define resultof(f, ...) typeof(Param<__VA_ARGS__>::Func(f))

template <class... Args>
class Param
{

    public:

        template <class R>
        static R Func (R (*) (Args...));

        template <class R, class C>
        static R Func (R (C::*) (Args...));

        template <class R, class C>
        static R Func (R (C::*) (Args...) const);

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that

```
template<typename... Args>
decltype( std::declval<T&>().f(std::declval<Args>()...) )
f(Args&&... args)
{
    return x.f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

should trigger SFINAE and discard any instantiation of `f` for which the return type is ill-formed (e.g. ambiguous or non-existant overload) instead of a hard error. I'm not quite sure though because `T` is a parameter of `proxy`, not `f` and I simply can't parse the relevant parts of the Standard (around 14.8.2 I believe). None of the examples provided in the non normative notes seems to apply.

Failing that, it's possible to use

```
template<typename U = T&, typename... Args>
decltype( std::declval<U>().f(std::declval<Args>()...) )
f(Args&&... args)
{
    return x.f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

for which my compiler happily accepts `proxy<int> p;`, unlike with the first option. `p.f();` results in a 'No matching function found' error, as is usual with SFINAE.

---

I recommend using the freestanding form of the operators where possible:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(Proxy<T> const& lhs, Proxy<U> const& rhs)
-> decltype( std::declval<T const&>() + std::declval<U const&>() )
{
    return lhs.x + rhs.x;
}
```

is a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, this solution seems to be working nicely, but strange for operators; needs `decltype(std::declval<T&>()(std::declval<Args>()...))` instead of `decltype(std::declval<T&>().operator () (std::declval<Args>()...))`

Comment: Any idea how to turn it into a macro? I've tried but failed so far.

Comment: @Frigo Perhaps that warrants its own question, I don't see anything special about what you're doing. What happens if you use `#define DEFINE_FORWARDING_MEMBER(member_name) \ ` and paste the above as a multi-line macro, substituting `f` with `member_name`?

Comment: It doesn't work the same way for functions and operators. For example I've tried with `decltype(std::declval<T&>())::operator () (etc)`, `std::declval<T&>().operator () (etc)`, but only `std::declval<T&>()(etc)` works with SFINAE, which makes it impossible to use the same macro as for functions. From a variadic macro I can not put each `T` type parameters in `std::declval<T>()` either. With templates I could, but then I couldn't pass it back to choose the appropriate function with their help. A `resultof(Class::function(Arguments))` with SFINAE should REALLY be a language feature.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to apply this to unary + and - operators either.

Comment: @Frigo Using `lval(arg0, ...)` should be preferred to `lval.operator()(arg0, ...)` anyway because a legitimate functor may expose its functionality through e.g. a conversion operator, not `operator()`. Generic code should be specified in terms of valid expressions, not whether a parameter type has an `operator()` -- those are implementation details.

Comment: @Frigo Added an example for `operator+`. I'm afraid you can't have one macro to do it all -- at best you can have a macro for each arity. A separate macro (or do it by hand) for each arity for those operators that must be members, too.

Comment: Still can't apply it to unary operators, but thank you for your solution nonetheless.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working. All I had to do is to declare them outside the class, that way they still remain template operators even if the class is instantiated. Otherwise they will remain non-template member operators and the compiler whines about not finding the operator in the underlying class.

Comment: @Frigo SFINAE only ever applies to templates and member functions are not templates, even if they're members of a template. In-class declaration could look like `template<typename U = T> decltype( -std::declval<U>() ) operator-() const;` for unary `operator-`.

Comment: Wow thank you, that is even better than the friend/non-member function approach of mine.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this seems trivial:

```
template <typename T> class Proxy : public T { };
```

Nothing else in C++ will give `Proxy<T>` all the members of T, for any T. The only bit missing is the ctors, but from your question I infer that you already know how to forward those.

Background: Practically speaking, the set of *possible* member names of `T` is infinite. Therefore, you can't find `.f()` by name lookup in `Proxy<T>`, and the only other scope in which a member name is looked up is the base class scope.

Comment: Well technically Proxy has a pointer to T instead of a member variable and makes additional checks to ensure it is not NULL for some operations, throwing exceptions if it is. I just didn't want to complicate the question further. Thank you for the input nonetheless, I really appreciate it.

Comment: C++0x brings inherited constructors: `using T::T;` to make your solution complete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to isolate the checking of the existence of `f` in the template parameter of `proxy` by an extra level. The following will allow you to call `proxy<X>::f()` in any way that you can call `X::f()`:

```
template<typename T,typename ... Args>
struct f_result
{
    typedef decltype(std::declval<T&>().f(std::declval<Args&&>()...)) type;
};

template<typename T>
struct proxy
{
    T val;

    template<typename ... Args>
    typename f_result<T,Args...>::type
    f(Args&& ... args)
    {
        return val.f(static_cast<Args&&>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Quick test:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout<<"X::f()"<<std::endl;
    }

    int f(int i)
    {
        std::cout<<"X::f("<<i<<")"<<std::endl;
        return i;
    }
};

struct Y
{};

struct Z
{
    int f()
    {
        std::cout<<"Z::f()"<<std::endl;
        return 42;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    proxy<X> px;
    px.f();
    int i=px.f(3);
    std::cout<<"i="<<i<<std::endl;

    proxy<Y> py;
    proxy<Z> pz;
    int j=pz.f();
    std::cout<<"j="<<j<<std::endl;
}
```

This works OK with g++ 4.5 and g++ 4.6 in -std=c++0x mode.