# accessing operator overloading of class which is wrapped by std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, overloading, shared-ptr

the idea is that I want a class which is wrapped by `std::shared_ptr`, can still be used
just like they weren't a pointer, for example the operator= which was defined in my class
can still be used after my class is wrapped by `std::shared_ptr`.

for example

```
template <class Ty> class shared_ptr_proxy : public std::shared_ptr<Ty> {
public:
    template<class Other> shared_ptr_proxy& operator=(const Other& rhs)
    {
        (*this->get()) = rhs;
        return *this;
    }
    template<class Other> explicit shared_ptr_proxy(Other * ptr) 
        : std::shared_ptr<Ty>(ptr){};
};

// usage :
shared_ptr_proxy<float> obj = shared_ptr_proxy<float>(new float);
obj = 3.14;
```

its work, but is there a way that i don't need to create `shared_ptr_proxy` or
inheriting a class from `std::shared_ptr` ?

and

if I do like this, is there a caveat that i should take care of?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just dereference the pointers? `*ptrA = *ptrB;`?

Comment: because the idea is to hide that it was actually a pointer

Comment: The knowledge that it's actually a pointer is usually a *feature* for shared mutable data. Otherwise, it's not obvious that different objects might alias to the same thing, and hence that `a = b` can change the value of `c`. No doubt there are cases where you do want to hide that it's a pointer, the most obvious to me being that it's not actually shared (despite using `shared_ptr`), it's a pImpl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want the proxy for. A full proxy might make it look entirely like you had the value, so you'd provide the conversion operators.

In such case, it might not be a good idea to inherit from `shared_ptr`, though, because you might be inheriting functions that you want to rely on the implicit conversions instead.

Compare how sorting orders the items:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class Ty> class shared_ptr_proxy   {
    std::shared_ptr<Ty> ptr;
public:
    template<class Other> explicit shared_ptr_proxy(Other * p) 
        : ptr(std::shared_ptr<Ty>(p)){};

    template<class Other> shared_ptr_proxy& operator=(const Other& other)
    {
        *ptr = other;
        return *this;
    }

    operator Ty& () { return *ptr; }
    operator const Ty& () const { return *ptr; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<shared_ptr_proxy<int> > vec {
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(10)), 
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(11)), 
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(9))
    };
    vec.back() = 8;  //use assignment
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());  //sort based on integer (not pointer) comparison
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';  //output stored values
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class Ty> class shared_ptr_proxy : public std::shared_ptr<Ty>   {
public:
    template<class Other> explicit shared_ptr_proxy(Other * p) 
        : std::shared_ptr<Ty>(p){};

    template<class Other> shared_ptr_proxy& operator=(const Other& other)
    {
        *this->get()= other;
        return *this;
    }

    operator Ty& () { return *this->get(); }
    operator const Ty& () const { return *this->get(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<shared_ptr_proxy<int> > vec {
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(10)), 
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(11)), 
        shared_ptr_proxy<int>(new int(9))
    };
    vec.back() = 8;  //the only thing that works
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());  //sort based on pointer values
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';  //outputs addresses
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`operator=` must be a member of the class that you're overloading. So no, you can't really do that non-intrusively.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this transparently, and it would probably be quite confusing if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think you can get away without inheriting or a custom wrapper, you can not overload `operator =` outside the definition of `shared_ptr`, and inheritance is not recommended in this case due to the nature of `shared_ptr`. However if you write a custom wrapper you can make it generic enough that it works for every type.

It is only possible in C++11, and even there it is difficult. You need `decltype` and `std::declval` for deducing the return type of the operator, and rvalue references and `std::forward` to forward the parameters perfectly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279416) and its answers for examples.

And as mentioned in that question, I have a pointer wrapper class implemented: http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/Frigo/Lang/ref

However it has some differences compared to what you want:

- Both `operator = (ref&)` and `operator = (ref&&)` only copies pointers. However, due to this and the proxied copy constructor, the implicit `operator = (const T&)` does a copy construction and a pointer copy instead of assignment or taking the address. This is a conscious choice of mine, assignment can create problems if the object is shared, and taking pointer from a stack allocated object is unsafe.
- Taking the return type of compound assignment operators like `operator +=` does not work due to an unimplemented feature of GCC. This is no problem since they are reinterpreted: `x += y` calls `x = (x + y)`, doing a copy/move construction and a pointer copy. This is also a conscious choice of mine, to keep the shared object unchanged.
- Garbage collected with Boehm GC instead of reference counted. This is also a conscious choice of mine, reference counting is a pretty bad alternative to garbage collection.

Answer (score -1):

Dereference shared pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<float> obj(new float);
*obj = 3.14;
```