# Why does my templated operator== not get used?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have defined `operator==` as follows:

```
template <class State>
bool operator==(const std::shared_ptr<const State> &lhs,
                const std::shared_ptr<const State> &rhs) {
    return *lhs == *rhs;
}
```

This operator does not get instantiated (in `gdb`, I cannot set the break-point on the return statement -- the line does not exist).

However, this operator should be used by `std::find` called in this line:

```
return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), el) != v.end();
```

I checked the type of `v` in the above line in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) whatis v
type = const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Domains::IncWorst const>> &
(gdb) whatis el
type = const std::shared_ptr<Domains::IncWorst const> &
```

Doesn't this match my templated `operator==` with `State` being `IncWorst`?

I implemented a toy example as follows and the example works, so I cannot understand why the real code does not.

```
template<class V, typename T>
bool in(const V &v, const T &el) {
    return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), el) != v.end();
}

struct MyState {
    MyState(int xx) : x(xx) {}
    bool operator==(const MyState &rhs) const {
        return x == rhs.x;
    }
    int x;
};

template <class State>
bool operator==(const std::shared_ptr<const State> &lhs,
                const std::shared_ptr<const State> &rhs) {
    return *lhs == *rhs;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const MyState>> v{
        std::make_shared<const MyState>(5)};
    auto p = std::make_shared<const MyState>(5);
    std::cout << in(v, p) << std::endl; // outputs 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just a guess, but are you sure that the template is available to the compiler in the file where you're calling find? In other words, is it #included or defined at the top of that file?

Comment: It surely is. I checked the output of the pre-processor to make sure.

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to solve the problem. Instead of defining a global == operator for your one use case, just pass a lambda comparator into `std::find_if`. Still curious about the technical reason why this doesn't work, though.

Comment: What's interesting to me is that your `operator==` in the global namespace has *almost* the same function signature as the `operator==` defined in the `std` namespace--the `std` `operator==` for `shared_ptr` templates on *both* arguments and doesn't have `const` template arguments for the `shared_ptr`s. I'm with templatetypedef on this one, though: don't make a global function that applies to all `shared_ptr` types, indicate which sort of equality you want. The default one will be assumed to be the one used by all readers of your code. I'd use a `eq` version of <memory>'s `owner_less`

Comment: @templatetypedef I have much code relying on testing for equality shared pointers to const states. I don't want to change all of it to use lambdas. Of course, I am going to make this template more precise in the future to catch only states and not pollute the global namespace so much.

Comment: @templatetypedef As for a different solution, I am thinking of creating a type `template <typename T> struct my_shared_ptr: std::shared_ptr<T> {...}`, whose `operator==` will be defined in terms of de-referencing.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In that case maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7513078/4899740) can help you.

Comment: It is usually considered a Very Bad Idea to inherit from standard library types that weren't designed to be inherited from. Honestly, it sounds like bad design to introduce custom operator overloading to standard library types for this purpose and although you've already done it, I'd strongly recommend migrating off it to a different approach.

Comment: @templatetypedef I thought that the only problem with inheriting from standard library types was that their member functions were not `virtual`. If there is something else, could you please give a pointer for further reading?

Comment: I don't have a pointer handy, but it's generally considered poor practice because (1) inheritance is generally now frowned upon in favor of composition when possible and (2) they don't have virtual destructors and so deletions through pointers or references lead to UB. Searching around this site should give some good pointers. Also, read "Effective C++" if you haven't yet done so - it's a phenomenal resource.

Comment: @templatetypedef (1) I think that composition is preferred to inheritance because of the Liskov principle, which is quite demanding, not because composition is inherently better. On the other hand, composition requires duplication of type definitions and defining a lot of member functions whose only task is to forward the call to the corresponding function of the base and that seems like a lot of work; (2) Virtual destructors are important only when one uses the base type pointer/reference to refer to the derived type, which is not so often the case in template code. cont'd

Comment: @templatetypedef cont'd. The two are actually strongly related (the Liskov principle is there to support run-time polymorphism). It follows that, in template code it might be OK to publically derive from a standard library type even when the Liskov principle is not strictly followed, such as the case with a shared pointer with different semantics for `operator==`. Please correct me if my logic is wrong.

Comment: @templatetypedef Please see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/65209/216771

Comment: You're right that it's not a hard-and-fast rule that you should always use composition over inheritance. However, I think that the particular design decisions you're making aren't as clean as, say, just writing a helper function that compares two shared_ptr<Model>s against one another. It's mostly that given the choice between overloading a global operator on a standard library type, publicly inheriting from a standard library type, or defining a helper function, the last option seems the least controversial and most readable.

Comment: @templatetypedef I dedicated a post to this issue (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/326094/216771) and a yet a better option was suggested in the comments there: private inheritance with using statements to make the desired member functions of the base available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator==` template is in the wrong namespace.

In order to be found by ADL, it must be either in the `std` namespace (which would be illegal, per [[**namespace.std**]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#1)) or in `Domains` (per [**[basic.lookup.argdep]**/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2)).

However, this is still highly dangerous, since if any template performing an equality comparison (e.g. but not limited to `std::find`) is instantiated both before and after your `operator==` template is declared, your whole program will be invalid per [**[temp.point]**/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#point-8) and [**[basic.def.odr]**/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#6).

If you *must* provide operator overload templates for `std::shared_ptr`s of your types, prefer to explicitly instantiate them after the declaration of each class, such that there is less chance of a template being instantiated somewhere the class is not visible:

```
struct MyState {
    // ...
};
template bool operator==<MyState>(
    const std::shared_ptr<MyState const>&,
    const std::shared_ptr<MyState const>&);
```

This could still be problematic if someone forward-declares `MyState` somewhere else, but it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: You are right! If I put `MyState` in my toy example into a namespace of its own, the example stops working!

Comment: As for the preferred solution, how about using a type derived from `std::shared_ptr<T>` which would define `operator==` as I want it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, that'd be fine. It'd be safer still to encapsulate `std::shared_ptr<T>` (that is, have it as a data member) as that gives you full control over operators and conversions.