# C++ template argument deduction with lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

I have the following template declaration

```
template<typename T>
void foo(function<void(T)> f){
    // ...
};
```

But when i call it like this

```
foo([](string s){ });
// visual studio 13 error message => 
// Error:  void foo(std::function<void(_Type)>)' : 
//could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<void(_Type)>' 
//from 'main::<lambda_58b8897709e10f89bb5d042645824f66>
```

Template argument deduction fails .
Why? how to fix it?

I have the same problem with variadic templates

```
template<typename ... Tn>
void foo(function<void(Tn ...)> f){
    // ...
};

int main() {
    foo<string,bool>([](string s,bool b){ }); // Works
    foo([](string s,bool b){ }); // Fails
}
```

But if i explicitly cast the lambda it works (!)

```
foo((function<void(string,bool)>) [](string s,bool b){ }); // Works

// Or even a simpler syntax with a macro
#define lmda_(a) (function<void a>)[&] a
foo( lmda_((string s, bool b)) { }); // Works (note the extra () )
```

Why template argument deduction fails ? and how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11500881/560648

Comment: This should work, and might be nicer…

#define lmda_(…) (function<void (__VA_ARGS__)>)[&] (__VA_ARGS__)
->
foo( lmda_(string s, bool b) { }); // notice the missing ()

e: you need to pre- and postfix va_args with 2 underscores (they turn into bold formatted text here)

Comment: *Robot's Law of Lambda Banality*: if your design cares about lambdas, it's wrong. (Also phrased simply as "lambdas are not special")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a non-deducible context. The template parameter `T` cannot be deduced.

Here is a simplest example. Given:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct X
 {
     X(T t) : data(t) {}
     T data;
 };

 template<typename T>
 void f(X<T> param);
```

Now you're doing something like this:

```
 f(100);
```

thinking that `T` will be deduced to `int`. NO. It will not be deduced to `int`. Because there could be more than one possibility for `T`. For example, there might be specializations as:

```
 template<>
 struct X<double>
 {
     X(int t) : data(t) {}
     int data;
 };

 template<>
 struct X<float> //another specialization
 {
     X(int t) : data(t) {}
     int data;
 };
```

So even though `t` is `int` (same as the type of `100`), the template argument could be `double` or `float` (or any other type).

Comment: Maybe you mean `f({100});`.

Comment: @Constructor: Edited to remove confusion! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The standard-library function is a type that can hold any object you
can invoke using the call operator () which means in other ways that it is 
 an object of type function is a function object.

During function instantiation foo([] (string str){}); 
There is no way the compiler would deduce the type of T for the "function" function object class
This way we explicitly specify the type which leads to neater way of describing the dependencies for the function.
    auto func1 =[](string str){};
    foo(func1);
    or
    foo([] (string str){});