# Proxying a std::function to a C function that wants an array of arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, binding, variadic-templates, std-function

I'm dealing with a C system that offers a hook of this form:

```
int (*EXTENSIONFUNCTION)(NATIVEVALUE args[]);
```

It's possible to register an EXTENSIONFUNCTION and the number of arguments it takes.

My idea was that I'd make a class `Extension` to wrap up an extension.  It would be able to be constructed from a std::function *(or any Callable, ideally, but let's just say it contains a std::function for now)*.  And the extension takes Value parameters, which wrap up NATIVEVALUE *(but are larger)*.  I'd automatically take care of the parameter count with `sizeof...(Ts)`, for instance.  It might look like this:

```
Extension<lib::Integer, lib::String> foo =
    [](lib::Integer i, lib::String s) -> int {
        std::cout << i;
        std::cout << s;
        return 0;
    }
```

Problem is that in order for the C library to register and call it, it wants that array-based interface.  :-/

I set out to try and get the compiler to write a little shim, but I don't see a way to do it.  I can have a variadic `operator()` on Extension, and do a runtime loop over the NATIVEVALUE to get an array of Value[].  But what do I do with that?  I can't call the std::function with it.

So it seems I need to make an EXTENSIONFUNCTION instance which calls my std::function, as a member of each Extension instance.

But basically I find myself up against a wall where I have a variadic templated class for the extension... and then a sort of "can't get there from here" in terms of taking this `NATIVEVALUE args[]` and being able to call the std::function with them.  If std::function would be willing to be invoked with a std::array of arguments, that would solve it, but of course that isn't how it works.

Is it possible to build a shim of this type?  The "ugly" thing I can do is just proxy to another array, like:

```
Extension<2> foo =
    [](lib::Value args[]) -> int {
        lib::Integer i (args[0]);
        lib::String s (args[1]);
        std::cout << i;
        std::cout << s;
        return 0;
    }
```

But that's not as ergonomic.  It seems impossible, without knowing the calling convention and doing some kind of inline assembly stuff to process the parameters and CALL the function *(and even that would work for functions only, not Callables in general)*.  But people here have proven the impossible possible before, usually by way of *"that's not what you want, what you actually want is..."*

---

**UPDATE:** I just found this, which seems promising...I'm still trying to digest its relevance:

["unpacking" a tuple to call a matching function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer)

*( Note: There are a few cross-cutting issues in what I aim to do.  Another point is type inference from lambdas.  Answer here seems to be the best bet on that... it appears to work, but I don't know if it's "kosher": [Initialize class containing a std::function with a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918758/initialize-class-containing-a-stdfunction-with-a-lambda/19934080#19934080) )*

Comment: As `EXTENSIONFUNCTION` doesn't seems to take a `void* userData` to be able to call your class `Extension`, I don't see how to solve your problem.

Comment: What is `NATIVEVALUE`? Maybe you can pass a pointer to `Extension` in the first element of the array.

Comment: I had a somewhat difficult time reading what you put in here, but I *think* maybe its [something like this](http://ideone.com/fJlkK6). If not, I hope it at least gives you some ideas. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks...sorry if the question was unclear, I elaborated.  But it's actually the reverse problem.  My goal is not to call an EXTENSIONFUNCTION in a pretty way--it's rather to be able to take a routine expressed as a std::function and allow the C project to call it as if it had an EXTENSIONFUNCTION signature.  So I need to fabricate a "shim" function pointer that takes this NATIVEVALUE array, that invokes the std::function with Value class instances.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense now. I originally thought you wanted to invoke a variadic function as a C-style callback, passing the variadic parameters down to the callback packed as `NATIVEVALUE`, which is obviously doable. The reverse, *unpacking* a `NATIVEVALUE[]` will be considerably harder. I'd have to mull that over, preferably with a good glass of single-malt =P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I managed to reduce the problem to its simplest form, you need a way to call an `std::function` taking its argument from a fixed-sized C-style array without having to create a run-time loop. Then, these functions may solve your problem:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename F, std::size_t... Indices>
auto apply_from_array_impl(F&& func, T (&arr)[N], std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(func)(arr[Indices]...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(func)(arr[Indices]...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename F,
         typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto apply_from_array(F&& func, T (&arr)[N])
    -> decltype(apply_from_array_impl(std::forward<F>(func), arr, Indices()))
{
    return apply_from_array_impl(std::forward<F>(func), arr, Indices());
}
```

Here is an example demonstrating how it can be used:

```
auto foo = [](int a, int b, int c)
    -> int
{
    return a + b + c;
};

int main()
{
    Value arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << apply_from_array(foo, arr); // prints 6
}
```

Of course, with the signature `int (*)(T args[])`, `args` is just a `T*` and you don't know its size at compile time. However, if you know the compile time size from somewhere else (from the `std::function` for example), you can still tweak `apply_from_array` to manually give the compile-time size information:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename F, std::size_t... Indices>
auto apply_from_array_impl(F&& func, T* arr, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(func)(arr[Indices]...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(func)(arr[Indices]...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename F,
         typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
auto apply_from_array(F&& func, T* arr)
    -> decltype(apply_from_array_impl<N>(std::forward<F>(func), arr, Indices()))
{
    return apply_from_array_impl<N>(std::forward<F>(func), arr, Indices());
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
int c_function(NATIVEVALUE args[])
{
    return apply_from_array<arity>(f, args);
}
```

In the example above, consider that `f` is an `std::function` and that `arity` is the arity of `f` that you managed to get, one way or another, at compile time.

**NOTE:** I used the C++14 `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence` but if you need your code to work with C++11, you can still use handcrafted equivalents, like `indices` and `make_indices` in the old question of mine that you linked.

---

**Aftermath:** the question being about [real code](https://github.com/hostilefork/rencpp/blob/develop/include/rencpp/extension.hpp), it was of course a little bit more complicated than above. The extension mechanism is designed so that everytime an extension function is called, C++ proxys above the C API (`lib::Integer`, `lib::String`, etc...) are created on the fly then passed to the user-defined function. This required a new method, `applyFunc` in `Extension`:

```
template<typename Func, std::size_t... Indices>
static auto applyFuncImpl(Func && func,
                          Engine & engine,
                          REBVAL * ds,
                          utility::indices<Indices...>)
    -> decltype(auto)
{
    return std::forward<Func>(func)(
        std::decay_t<typename utility::type_at<Indices, Ts...>::type>{
            engine,
            *D_ARG(Indices + 1)
        }...
    );
}

template <
    typename Func,
    typename Indices = utility::make_indices<sizeof...(Ts)>
>
static auto applyFunc(Func && func, Engine & engine, REBVAL * ds)
    -> decltype(auto)
{
    return applyFuncImpl(
        std::forward<Func>(func),
        engine,
        ds,
        Indices {}
    );
}
```

`applyFunc` takes the function to call an calls it with instances of the appropriate types (`Integer`, `String`, etc...) on the fly from the underlying C API created on the fly with an `Engine&` and a `REBVAL*`.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help...above and beyond the call of duty...!