# Casting function pointer to functor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function pointer type imported from another .hpp file. Something like:

```
typedef void (*PFN_func)(int i);
```

I want to create a functor of the same type:

```
std::function<PFN_func>
```

But this doesn't work.
I don't want a solution like

```
std::function<void(int)>
```

Because mt function pointer definition is much more complicated

Comment: `std::function` wants a function type as its template parameter - which is not the same as pointer-to-function type. There's a difference between `void(int)` and `void(*)(int)`. `PFN_func` is a typedef for the latter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
std::function<std::remove_pointer<PFN_func>::type>
```

Removing the pointer from `void (*)(int)` gives the function type `void(int)`.

For the case of a general callable, see [Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda)