# Writing a template function that evaluates a lambda function with any return type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I want to write an 'evaluation' function that takes as input a function of unspecified return type that takes an integer, and an integer to call that function with.

What I've come up with is the following:

```
#include <functional>
template<typename T>
T eval(function<T(int)> f, int x) {
    return f(x);
}
```

Let's say I have an `auto func = [] (int x) -> long { return (long)x * x; }` which I want to evaluate using the above function. The way I used template functions before was to simply call it as I would any other function and let the compiler deduce the type.

However, this doesn't work with this `eval` function. `eval<long>(func, 5)` compiles and works fine, however `eval(func, 5)` does not:

```
Aufgaben10.5.cpp:23:25: error: no matching function for call to 'eval(main()::__lambda0&, int)'
     cout << eval(func, 5) << endl;
                         ^
Aufgaben10.5.cpp:23:25: note: candidate is:
Aufgaben10.5.cpp:8:3: note: template<class T> T eval(std::function<T(int)>, int)
 T eval(function<T(int)> f, int x) {
   ^
Aufgaben10.5.cpp:8:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Aufgaben10.5.cpp:23:25: note:   'main()::__lambda0' is not derived from 'std::function<T(int)>'
     cout << eval(func, 5) << endl;
```

Is there a way to write a template function that has the same return type as the lambda function without explicitly passing the type to the template, so that I can simply call `eval(func, 5)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda

Comment: I'd get rid of `function` at all here, pass `T&& f` to the `eval`, and `decltype` the return type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use `decltype`?

```
template<typename Function>
auto eval(Function&& f, int x) -> decltype(std::forward<Function>(f)(x))
{
   return std::forward<Function>(f)(x);
}
```

Comment: I'd take `Function` by `&&`. Otherwise yeah, that, +1.

Comment: Because I did not know about it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Not only needless; in case of noncopyable function objects it forbids the use at all.

Comment: If you're going to take `Function` by `&&`, you should call it as `std::forward<Function>(f)(x)` in case it's ref qualified.

Comment: It's possible that the rvalue- and lvalue-qualified call operators of `f` return different types. The return type should really be `decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(x))`.

Comment: Except that `F` is named `Function` here. :) Also, if C++14 is an option, `decltype(auto)` is another alternative.