# Is it possible to call a function with all arguments default constructed?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a function like `std::invoke`, but this function calls all arguments of the given function automatically with the default constructed types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
// e.g. for a single arg 
struct Test{
    void operator()(int i) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << "\n";
    }
};

int main(){
  Test test;
  std::invoke(test, {});  // this doesn't work, would like it to call with default constructed int (0).
  return 0;
}
```

I would like something like

```
int main()
{
  Test test;
  invoke_with_defaults(test); // prints 0
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not provide default arguments for the parameters?

Comment: e.g. using a 3rd party library

Comment: `{}` doesn't work because the compiler might see that it is a default construction, but cannot tell what type it is supposed to be.

Comment: It is *sometimes* possible but very convoluted. Why would you need it?

Comment: basically what you want is to avoid typing parentheses at the end of a function which has all arguments defined as default? Like, use `test` instead of `test()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a class with a templated conversion `operator`, returning `{}` for any type:

```
struct DefaultConstruct
{
    DefaultConstruct() = default;
    DefaultConstruct(const DefaultConstruct &) = delete;
    DefaultConstruct &operator=(const DefaultConstruct &) = delete;
    template <typename T> operator T() && {return {};}
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::invoke(test, DefaultConstruct{});
}
```

It's then possible to write a template that automatically determines how many of those have to be passed:

```
template <typename F, typename ...P>
decltype(auto) InvokeDefault(F &&func)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, P...>)
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), P{}...);
    else
        return InvokeDefault<F, P..., DefaultConstruct>(std::forward<F>(func));
}

int main()
{
    Test test;
    InvokeDefault(test);
}
```

And if the argument isn't callable at all, you get a compilation error after exceeding some implementation-defined limit (on Clang I got up to 256).

Answer (score 1):

Initializer lists like `{}` cannot be forwarded as a parameter due not work due to language restrictions.

But you can mimick `{}` by wrapping it into a `Defaulter` class which can be passed around:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
// e.g. for a single arg 
struct Test{
    void operator()(int i) {
        std::cout << std::to_string(i) << "\n";
    }
};

struct Defaulter{

    template<typename T>
    operator T(){
        return {};
    }
};

int main(){
  Test test;
  std::invoke(test, Defaulter{}); 
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867127/498437) to create a tuple of all of the argument types, and then pass a default constructed instance of it to `std::apply`.  The specialisation list would need to be quite long though to cover all of the `const`, `volatile`, `noexcept`, and ref-qualified variants though, and of course it cannot work with template or overloaded functions.

[Eg](https://godbolt.org/z/sEK54zsYK):

```
template <typename T>
struct arg_extractor : arg_extractor<decltype(&T::operator())> {
};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct arg_extractor<R (*)(Args...)> {
    using type = std::tuple<R, Args...>;
};
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct arg_extractor<R (C::*)(Args...)> {
    using type = std::tuple<R, Args...>;
};
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct arg_extractor<R (C::*)(Args...) const> {
    using type = std::tuple<R, Args...>;
};
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct arg_extractor<R (C::*)(Args...) noexcept> {
    using type = std::tuple<R, Args...>;
};
template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct arg_extractor<R (C::*)(Args...) const noexcept> {
    using type = std::tuple<R, Args...>;
};
// All the rest...

template <typename T>
using arg_extractor_t = typename arg_extractor<T>::type;
```