# Deducing template parameter from functor argument type

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have the following code that is meant to accept a Qt QVariant and apply a functor if the variant contains a value:

```
template<typename T, typename Functor>
inline QVariant map(const QVariant& v, Functor f)
{
    return v.isValid()
            ? QVariant{f(qvariant_cast<T>(v))}
            : v;
}
```

My problem is that the compiler cannot deduce the type of T when I invoke this function as

```
map(someFuncReturningQVariant(), [](const QByteArray& array) -> QString {
    return array.toString();
});
```

The compiler complains (cleaned up from the original error, which has longer type names):

```
error: no matching function for call to `map(QVariant, <lambda(const QByteArray&)>)`
note: candidate is:
    template<class T, class Functor> QVariant map(const QVariant&, Functor).
note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
      couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
```

This is because QVariant erases the type of the object it contains at runtime.  (It still knows it internally, much like `boost::any`, and `qvariant_cast<T>()` gets the original object back).

**How can I capture the type of the variable passed to the `Functor`** and use it elsewhere?  Alternatively, how can I specify that `Functor` takes a parameter of type `T`?  (I suspect these are actually the same question, or that they at least have the same answer.)

Note that my approach works fine with `std::optional`, because the types are not erased:

```
using std::experimental::optional;

template<typename T, typename Functor>
inline auto map(const optional<T>& v, Functor f) -> optional<decltype(f(*v))>
{
    return v ? optional<decltype(f(*v))>{f(*v)}
             : v;
}
```

Also note that the QVariant code works fine if I manually specify the type:

```
map<QByteArray>(someFuncReturningQVariant(), [](const QByteArray& array) -> QString {
    return array.toString();
});
```

But of course, this is much uglier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you want is: given a functor, `F`, identify the decayed type of its first argument.

To that end, we need [`function_traits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/2069064), with which we can do:

```
template <typename F>
using first_arg = std::decay_t<typename function_traits<F>::template arg<0>::type>;
```

Which we use:

```
template<typename Functor>
inline QVariant map(const QVariant& v, Functor f)
{
    using T = first_arg<Functor>;

    return v.isValid()
            ? QVariant{f(qvariant_cast<T>(v))}
            : v;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's an arcane `using` statement; I wish C++ had something like Rust's `where` clause.  Oh well.  Is there a canonical `function_traits` or is it just something that people have written because it's useful?

Comment: @Barry function_traits is a nice utility. I thought you might be interested to know that it fails for std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1)

Comment: @RichardHodges You can't deduce the argument type of a function template, right? You'd have to provide it.

Comment: @Barry I think it could be done, decltype(bind(F, Args&&...)) gives the type of the bind object and the type/class of the function object. Then there'd have to be some mpl logic to find the nth placeholder using std::is_placeholder<> and map those back to the arguments of F. Not something I fancy doing right now, it's half past midnight here, but food for thought?

Answer (score 2):

```
map<QByteArray>(someFuncReturningQVariant(), [](auto&& array){
  return array.toString();
});
```

is the C++14 way to do that: don't specify the type in the lambda, but rather as (only) a template parameter.

Also note `->QString` is redundant in C++11 or 14.

Alternatively, know that `QVariant` is not a type ameniable to mapping.  Do the cast explicitly external to your map function.

Map the `QVariant` to a `optional<T&>` externally (or a `T*`), and return an `optional<std::result_of_t<F(T&)>>` (or a `QVariant` if you like throwing away information).

Comment: Gotcha.  I had stumbled upon this earlier and forgot about it.  Lambda type deduction is very cool.  And finally, I must return QVariant, because I'm implementing a Qt proxy model.