# Can I default the return type of this Transform template function?

Tags: c++, templates

Currently, to use the following...

```
template< class ResultCollection, class Collection, typename Transformation >
ResultCollection Transform(const Collection& c, Transformation t)
{
    ResultCollection result(c.size());
    transform(c.begin(), c.end(), result.begin(), t);
    return result;
}
```

... you need to supply the return type:

```
auto result = Transform< std::vector<int> >( someInputCollection, [] (SomeType& element) { return ElementToInt(element); });
```

Is it possible to default the template args so that by default you'll get a vector containing elements of whatever type the lambda returns?

I got to this:

```
template< class Collection, typename Transformation, class ResultCollection = std::vector< std::result_of_t<Transformation> > >
ResultCollection Transform(const Collection& c, Transformation t)
{
    ResultCollection result(c.size());
    transform(c.begin(), c.end(), result.begin(), t);
    return result;
}
```

But that gives me this:

```
C2783: 'ResultCollection Transform(const Collection &,Transformation)' : could not deduce template argument for 'ResultCollection'
```

And I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Apologies for updating my question 3 times! I'll get it right one day.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code. The first is missing `typename`s:

```
class ResultCollection = std::vector< typename std::iterator_traits<typename Collection::iterator>::value_type > 
                                      ^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^
```

But the second is that you're passing in entirely the wrong type! That's all well and good if your `Transformation` doesn't actually change the value type of the collection, but what if it did this?

```
std::vector<char> collection;
auto result = Transform(collection, [](char c) { return std::string(c, 1); });
```

You need your resulting `vector` to contain the type that the `Transformation` gives:

```
class ResultCollection = std::vector<
    std::result_of_t<Transformation(decltype(*std::declval<Collection>().begin()))>
>
```

And, btw, what if that result type isn't default-constructible? You're assuming it is here:

```
ResultCollection result(c.size());
```

Probably want to do this instead:

```
ResultCollection result;
result.reserve(c.size());
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(result), t);
```

Or really:

```
ResultCollection result;
result.reserve(c.size());
for (const auto& elem : c) {
    result.push_back(t(elem));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `function_traits` provided by [kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/4342498) to get the return type for the lambda and set it to the default.  Using that you would get

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
// For generic types, directly use the result of the signature of its 'operator()'

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
// we specialize for pointers to member function
{
    enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };
    // arity is the number of arguments.

    typedef ReturnType result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
        // the i-th argument is equivalent to the i-th tuple element of a tuple
        // composed of those arguments.
    };
};

template< class Collection, typename Transformation, class ResultCollection = std::vector< typename function_traits<Transformation>::result_type > >
ResultCollection Transform(const Collection& c, Transformation t)
{
    ResultCollection result(c.size());
    transform(c.begin(), c.end(), result.begin(), t);
    return result;
}
```

And you can see it running in this <kbd>[Live Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/4342498)</kbd>