# How to get all parameters' types from parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-traits

I have the following piece of code where I define `struct quick` with templated `static` method `random` with some specializations:

( I used `function_traits` from other SO answer. Attached on the bottom for reference.)

```
struct quick
{
  template <typename T>
  static T random();

  template <typename F>
  static void check(F f)
  {

    constexpr auto arity = function_traits<F>::arity; // easy :)
    std::cout << arity << std::endl;
    typedef typename function_traits<F>::template arg<0>::type type0; // easy:)
    // how to get all types of all F's parameters?
  }
};

template <>
std::string quick::random<std::string>()
{
  return std::string("test");
}

template <>
int quick::random<int>()
{
  return 1;
}
```

I would like to get all types of `F`'s parameters inside `check` so that I can generate a `tuple` with random entries (based on my `random` method specializations).

Like so:

```
auto t0 = std::make_tuple(quick::random<AllTypes>()...); //pseudo code
auto t =
    std::make_tuple(quick::random <
                                  function_traits<F>::template arg<std::make_index_sequence<arity>>::type...
                                  >
                                  ()...
                     );
```

I tried with something like:

```
template<typename F, typename ...TIdxs>
using ArgTypes = typename function_traits<F>::template arg<TIdxs>::type...;

// ...
// inside check

typedef ArgTypes<F, std::make_index_sequence<arity>> types;
```

but failed miserably:

```
main.cpp:80:72: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘...’ token
 using ArgTypes = typename function_traits<F>::template arg<TIdxs>::type...;
                                                                        ^
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void quick::check(F, D)’:
main.cpp:98:15: error: ‘ArgTypes’ does not name a type
       typedef ArgTypes<F, std::make_index_sequence<arity>> types;
```

---

I have used `function traits` utilities from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/675100) SO answer.

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits : function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
// For generic types, directly use the result of the signature of its 'operator()'

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
// we specialize for pointers to member function
{
    enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };
    // arity is the number of arguments.

    typedef ReturnType result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
        // the i-th argument is equivalent to the i-th tuple element of a tuple
        // composed of those arguments.
    };
};
```

Comment: As usual, function traits onky works sometimes.  `auto f=[](auto&&x){return 2*x;}`.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in `function_traits`, you already *have* all the argument types. All you have to do is expose them:

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
// we specialize for pointers to member function
{
    enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };

    using result_type = ReturnType;

    using all_args = std::tuple<Args...>; // <-- add this

    template <size_t i> // <-- consider making this an alias template
    using arg = std::tuple_element_t<i, all_args>;
};
```

And now, getting *all* the function arguments is just `function_traits<F>::all_args`.

---

If you don't want to change `function_traits`, we just have to add an external metafunction:

```
template <class F, class = std::make_index_sequence<function_traits<F>::arity>>
struct all_args;

template <class F, size_t... Is>
struct all_args<F, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<typename function_traits<F>::template arg<Is>::type...>;
};

template <class F>
using all_args_t = typename all_args<F>::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class=void,std::size_t...Is>
auto tupler(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f){
    return std::make_tuple(
      f(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Is>{})...
    );
  }
} 
template<std::size_t N>
auto tupler(){
  return tupler(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

This lets you expand parameter packs inline and produce a tuple.

Simply

```
auto t = tupler<ArgCount>()([&](auto i){
  return random<typename func_trait::arg<i>::type>();
});
```

Where `func_trait` is an alias to the thing above.

As an aside, replace `struct arg` with a `using` alias.  Cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that is what you want but... what about modifying `quick` in the following way?

```
struct quick
{
  template <typename T>
  static T random();

  template<typename F, std::size_t I>
     using ArgTypes = typename function_traits<F>::template arg<I>::type;

  template<typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
     using ArgTuple = std::tuple< ArgTypes<F, Is>... >;

  template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
  static ArgTuple<F, Is...> makeArgTuple ()
   { return make_tuple(quick::random<Is>()...); }

  template <typename F>
  static void check(F f)
  {

    constexpr auto arity = function_traits<F>::arity; // easy :)
    std::cout << arity << std::endl;

    typedef typename function_traits<F>::template arg<0>::type type0; // easy:)

    auto t = ArgTuple<F, std::make_index_sequence<arity>::type> ();

    auto t2 = makeArgTuple<F, std::make_index_sequence<arity>::type>();
  }

};
```

You were wrong passing `typename`s `TIdxs` to `arg`; `arg` needs a `std::size_t`.

Take into account that `std::make_index_sequence` it's a C++14 feature (but it's easy to create it in C++11 too).

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: regarding `TIdxs`: but I wanted to expand it so that I would get in results: `arg<0>, arg<1>, arg<2> ... `

Comment: @Patryk - sure; but as `std::size_t`, not as `typename`; I mean: is't wrong `template<typename F, typename ...TIdxs>`; should be `template<typename F, std::size_t ...TIdxs>`

Comment: Ahh yeah. You're right. But still I cannot get my end result `auto t = std::make_tuple(quick::random< ...what_here... >());`

Comment: @Patryk - I see... I don't think it's possible directly, but I've modified the answer, adding a `makeArgTuple()` method and an use example (see `auto t2 = ...`)