# Template specialization with non-empty template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, type-deduction

I have difficulties to understand the following code

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};
// For generic types, directly use the result of the signature of its 'operator()'

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
// we specialize for pointers to member function
{
  // ...
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](int i) { return long(i*10); };

    typedef function_traits<decltype(lambda)> traits;

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

which occurs in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/7006673.

Here,

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
```

seems to indicate a specialization of the template class

```
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
```

however, the template parameter list of the specialization `template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>` is not empty (i.e., is not equal to `template <>`).
Can someone please help me to understand, what kind of specialization this is and how the template parameters `ClassType`, `ReturnType`, and `Args` are deduced?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What kind of specialization this is?

This is a [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). `type_traits` is explicitly instantiated with:

```
T = ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const
```

But this `T` is dependent on `ReturnType`, `ClassType`, and `Args`. That is why you don't have `template <>` in the declaration (that would be a [full specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)), but a template declaration with new parameters describing a particular kind of `T`.

> How the template parameters ClassType, ReturnType, and Args are deduced?

They are deduced when the template is instantiated with an expression that suits this specialization. Here, `ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const` can only be substituted with a pointer to a method.

This is an example of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Comment: Thank you very much. One question remains: I thought type deduction can be done only for template parameters of functions and not for those of structs and classes -- am I wrong?

Comment: Implicit instantiation can be done only for template parameters of functions: you explicitly pass arguments when calling the function, so their types can be implicitly deduced. Here `function_traits<decltype(lambda)>` is an explicit instantiation with `T=decltype(lambda)`

Comment: Thank you! And the deduction of `ReturnType`, `ClassType` and `Args` based on `decltype(lambda)` can be done since `decltype(lambda)` is an template parameter -- is that right?

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial specialization.   It can't be an "anything" like something that just takes `typename T`, but it still has some variability in it, so it's not a full specialization.

Also, the things that you're looking to match up are the number of types in the original struct/class's template line and the `<...>` after the name in the specializations.  It's kind of weird because it's asymmetrical.

In your partial specialization:

```
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
```

All three of the templated types combined still only create a single type - a pointer to member function.  That is the same number of types as the "parent" templated type, even though that single type is broken down into 3 additional templated types in the specialization.

```
// this is what I'm calling the "master template", this isn't an official term
template<class A, class B, ......., class N>
class Foo{};

template</*...This can have as many (or 0) entries as you need for this specialization...*/>
class Foo</*...This must have the same number as master template above, but can be broken down into as many smaller pieces as you want...*/> {};
```