# std::declval vs crtp, cannot deduce method return type from incomplete type

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, crtp, declval

I am trying to do something like this (in c++11):

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct base {
    using type = decltype( std::declval<T>().foo() );
};

struct bar : base<bar> {
    int foo() { return 42;}
};

int main() {
    bar::type x;
}
```

which fails with

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'struct base<bar>':
prog.cc:8:14:   required from here
prog.cc:5:46: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct bar'
     using type = decltype( std::declval<T>().foo() );
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
prog.cc:8:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct bar'
 struct bar : base<bar> {
        ^~~
```

**How can I declare an alias to the return type of `bar::foo` in `base` ? Is it not possible?**

This question seems to be rather related: [Special behavior for decltype of call operator for incomplete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518910/special-behavior-for-decltype-of-call-operator-for-incomplete-types), though I couldnt manage to apply the answer given there to my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make `type` a template type alias, so that users can instantiate it after the definition of `bar` is available. This will change the final syntax from `bar::type` to `bar::type<>`.

```
template <typename T>
struct base {
    template <typename G = T>
    using type = decltype( std::declval<G>().foo() );
};

struct bar : base<bar> {
    int foo() { return 42;}
};

int main() {
    bar::type<> x;
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T51xgg)

Comment: I think now I also understand the reasoning in the answer I linked :) I dont like the `bar::type<>` too much but I could live with that

Comment: Unfortunately, `type<>` is not that useful inside a class scope. E.g., you can't write `type<> foo2();` for a `base`'s of `bar`'s member function without using similar `G = T` trick.