# Overload templated lambda without knowing argument type for non-templated parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Given lambdas with the following structure:

```
auto lambda_1 = [](int x, auto p) -> void {...};
auto lambda_2 = [](float x, auto p) -> int {...};
```

I want to extract the type of `x`, as well as the return type, given a known type for `p`.

The return type is fairly simple as long as `x` is default-constructible (which I can make a requirement without problem):

```
template<typename CB_T>
void foo(CB_T cb) {
  using res_type = decltype(cb({}, std::declval<KnownP>()));
}
```

Similarly, if the second argument wasn't infered, I could easily find the first argument's type using something like [function_traits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/4442671).

I know that I can trigger overload resolution the way I want, as evidenced by how I extract the result type without knowing what the type of `x` is, so I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to pull this off.

It feels like I have every piece of the puzzle, but I can't seem to be able to figure how to get the type of the overloaded function in that scenario in order to extract the type of `x`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? In general, this isn't possible without reflection. For *specifically* lambdas of the form `[](T, auto)` with no SFINAE shenanigans, this is possible, but that seems weirdly specific.

Comment: @Barry it's huh... convoluted...  I need this in order to allocate a temporary buffer to pass as a reference to a templated sub-process for it to fill prior to calling the lambda. I need the second parameter to be templated because the actual type is going to be very opaque, and I really don't want to impose it on users (I also want the lambdas to be reusable with different opaque types). [reference](https://github.com/FrancoisChabot/abulafia/issues/15)

Comment: @Barry I actually would like to be able to accept arbitrary functors and not JUST lambdas, but asking users to wrap functors in lambdas is acceptable if necessary. (I really want to support closures though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific case that you are dealing with lambdas that:

- Take two arguments: the first of which is a non-template, and the second of which is a template
- Have a return type that is valid for all template parameters (e.g. has no `enable_if`, etc.)

Then you can use a fake deducer type for the first argument:

```
struct arbitrary { template <class T> operator T(); };
using res = decltype(cb(arbitrary{}, std::declval<KnownP>()));
```

Or you can use `function_traits` to look up the specific `operator()` we're going to be using:

```
using oper = decltype(&CB_T::template operator()<KnownP>);
using arg0 = typename function_traits<oper>::template arg<0>::type;
using res = decltype(cb(std::declval<arg0>(), std::declval<KnownP>());
```

---

Both are really specific to this particular lambda layout though.

Comment: `decltype(&CB_T::template operator()<KnownP>)` Doy! Why didn't I think of this? That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll give it a try right away.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `arbitrary{}` instead of just `{}`?

Comment: As far as the structure being specific. I actually would like to allow a 2-3 different argument configurations, but I should be able to sort it out using `std::is_invocable`

Comment: @Frank If the type isn't default copy-list-initializable, you can't use `{}`. `arbitrary` will just work.