# Check if function return type is the same as an STL container type value

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm working with a struct that takes a generic function and a generic STL container, but i want to make a type check in the constructor in order to raise an error if the return type of the function is different from the constructor type: is it possible to do something like this without changing the template?

```
template<class Function, class Container>
struct task{
        Function f;
        Container& c;

        task(Function func, Container& cont):f(func), c(cont){
                //error if mismatch between container type and function return type
        }
}; 

int multiply(int x){ return x*10; }

int main(){
        vector<int> v;
        int c=10;
        auto stateless = [](float x){ return x*10;};
        auto stateful = [&c](int x){ return x*c;};

        task t(multiply, v); //SAME TYPE: OKAY!
        task tt(stateless, v); //TYPE MISMATCH: ERROR!

        return 0;
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: and the arguments of the function are ... ?

Comment: @max66 I added a bit more context; it can be a function with or without parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand completely but... if the "generic funcion" isn't a generic-lambda or a template `operator()` in a class/struct... you tagged C++17 so you can use deduction guides so you can deduce the type returned from the function using `std::function`'s deduction guides.

Something as

```
decltype(std::function{std::declval<Function>()})::result_type
```

For the value type of the container is usually available the `value_type` type.

So, defining a couple of `using` types inside the body of the struct, you can write

```
template <typename F, typename C>
struct task
 {
   using rtype = typename decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()})::result_type;
   using vtype = typename C::value_type;

   // ...

   task (F func, C & cont) : f{func}, c{cont}
    { static_assert( std::is_same<rtype, vtype>{} );}
 };
```

But observe that the `static_assert()` inside the constructor use only elements that aren't specific of the constructor.

This way, if you have to develop (by example) ten constructors, you have to write ten times the same `static_assert()` inside the ten constructors bodies.

I suggest to place the `static_assert()` inside the body of the struct so you have to write it only one time.

I mean

```
template <typename F, typename C>
struct task
 {
   using rtype = typename decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()})::result_type;
   using vtype = typename C::value_type;

   static_assert( std::is_same<rtype, vtype>{} );

   // ...
 };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template <typename F, typename C>
struct task
 {
   using rtype = typename decltype(std::function{std::declval<F>()})::result_type;
   using vtype = typename C::value_type;

   static_assert( std::is_same<rtype, vtype>{} );

   F   f;
   C & c;

   task (F func, C & cont) : f{func}, c{cont}
    { }
 }; 

int multiply (int x)
 { return x*10; }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int> v;

   int c=10;

   auto stateless = [](float x){ return x*10;};
   auto stateful  = [&c](int x){ return x*c;};

   task t1(multiply, v);  // compile
   task t2(stateful, v);  // compile
   task t3(stateless, v); // compilation error
 }
```

But remember: this function doen't works with generic-lambdas.

In that case I don't know how to solve the problem and I suppose isn't solvable at all without knowing the type of the input parameters.

Comment: Great to see that you simply use declvall with std::function and forward the callable as template-parm. Nice! +1

Comment: @Klaus - yes, C++17 deduction guides are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static_assert` with [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check type equality at compile time.

If your lambda function always takes no parameters, you can use `decltype(f())`
to get the function return type, else you will need
[`std::result_of / std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) or a [function traits implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7943765/1941973).

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class Function, class Container>
struct task{
        Function f;
        Container& c;

        task(Function func, Container& cont):f(func), c(cont){
                static_assert(
                        std::is_same<
                                decltype(f()),                 // type of function return value
                                typename Container::value_type // type of values stored in container
                        >::value,
                        "incompatible function" // error message
                );
        }
};
```

Comment: can you show me how to do it with functions that take parameters without using that function traits implementation, please?( I added a bit more context to the question)

Comment: @joyfantastic " without using that function traits ". What do you mean?

Comment: @Klaus without using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda/7943765#7943765

Comment: for functions with arbitrary parameter lists you either need to include a function traits implementation as in the linked solution or you need to change your template to include the parameter types (see the solution by @Klaus)

Answer (score 1):

I see no way to go ahead without using any kind of helper template to determine the parameter list here!

So the following solution is still based on [Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda/7943765#7943765)

For having function pointers and callable classes like lambdas, it only needs an specialized template instance.

```
template <typename CLASS>
struct function_traits_impl
: public function_traits_impl<decltype(&CLASS::operator())>
{};

template <typename CLASS, typename RET, typename... ARGS>
struct function_traits_impl< RET(CLASS::*)(ARGS...) const>
{
    using args_type = std::tuple<ARGS...>;
    using ret_type = RET;
};

template <typename CALLABLE > struct function_traits: public    function_traits_impl< CALLABLE >{};

template< typename RET, typename... ARGS >
struct function_traits< RET(*)(ARGS...) >
{
    using args_type = std::tuple<ARGS...>;
    using ret_type = RET;
};


template < typename CLASS, typename CONTAINER, typename RET, typename ... ARGS> struct task;
template< typename CLASS, typename CONTAINER, typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
struct task< CLASS, CONTAINER, RET, std::tuple<ARGS...> >
{
    using FUNC = std::function< RET(ARGS...)>;

    FUNC func;
    CONTAINER cont;

    task(  FUNC _func,  CONTAINER& _cont): func{_func}, cont{_cont}
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same<
            //decltype( func( std::declval<PARMS>()...) ), // but is already known from given template parms!
            RET,
            typename CONTAINER::value_type
            >::value,
            "wrong return type, did not match with container type"
            );

    }
};

template <typename FUNC, typename CONTAINER >
task(FUNC, CONTAINER) -> task< FUNC, CONTAINER, typename function_traits<FUNC>::ret_type, typename function_traits<FUNC>::args_type>;



int Any( int ) { return 0; }
float WrongAny( int, int ) { return 1.1; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    //task t1{ [](int, int)->float { return 0; } , v}; // fails with assert as expected
    task t2{ [](int, int)->int { return 0; } , v}; //Works!
    task t3{ &Any , v}; // Works
    //task t4{ &WrongAny, v }; fails as expected
}
```

This solution simply uses user defined deduction guide to forward the found parms from the trait which is helpful as you also use c++17.

Hint:
Generic lambdas cant be used, because if the parameters to call the lambda are unknown, how you could determine the parameters "automatically". It is quite easy to specify the parameters with the call and get the return type, but passing an generic lambda or an object with overloaded call operator needs to specify which of the functions/methods are should be used. So if you need generic lambdas or overloaded methods in class objects simply specify params manually! There can't be a trick in any language which allows you to give a set of optional calls and determine automatically which call should be used if no other information is available. As said: If params for the call are present, simply use them!

Remark:
If you use this solution, you only get a single template instance for all calls with same parameter set to the function call which may save some memory ;) But it uses a std::function to store teh callable which takes some runtime... You have now two solutions which differs in the results but both are usable ;)

Comment: this way my task struct can't accept lambda functions though

Comment: @joyfantastic: New attempt ;) It works but is still based on the traits example

Comment: "I see no way to go ahead without using any kind of helper template to determine the parameter list here!" - correct (I suppose) before C++17, but the OP tagged C++17 and in C++17 you can use `std::function`'s deduction guides in a simpler way (see my answer for an example).

Comment: @Klaus it works great, but now I can't hold "standard" functions as they don't have operator() ahahah! as I said i would like to use both lambdas and functions

Comment: @joyfantastic - Klaus modified his answer and now works also with lambdas (but not with generic lamdas, unfortunately (as my solution, after all))

Comment: @joyfantastic: now it works also for standard functions. Generic lambdas cant be uses, because if the parameters to call the lambda are unknwon, how you could determine the parameters "automatically". It is quite easy to specify the parameters with the call and get the return type, but passing an generic lambda or an object with overloaded call operator needs to specify which of the functions/methods are should be used. So if you need generic lambdas or overloaded methods in class objects simply specify params manually!

Comment: @Klaus thank you for the nice explanation, I'll try both and see!

Comment: @joyfantanstic of course i did, but it's not shown publicly as I have less than 15 reputation points

Comment: @joyfantastic: Ubs, sometimes is quite hard to understand SO rules... Have fun! ;)