# How to get return type and parameter type of a generic lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, generic-lambda

I want to get return type and parameter type of a lambda.
[Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda)give a solution.But it does not work for generic lambda.

```
template<typename F>
struct function_traits :public
    function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())> {};

template<typename R,typename C,typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(Args...)const>:public
    function_traits<R(Args...)>{
  constexpr static size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);
};

auto f1 = [](int x) {return x+1; };
Print(function_traits<decltype(f1)>::arity);  //return 1
auto f2 = [](auto x) {return x+1; };
Print(function_traits<decltype(f2)>::arity);  //error
```

So how to solve it to get return type and parameter type of a generic lambda?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to invalidate existing answers. Instead, please post a new question.

Comment: both variants cannot be compiled, first case results in lambda object being casted to function pointer

Answer (score 3):

Generic lambdas are lambdas where the `operator()` overload is a template function. If a template function's parameter is deduced, then it has no type; only an individual instantiation of such a template has a parameter with a type.

`auto` isn't a type; it's a placeholder that means "this is a template parameter".

Comment: Now  I m confused about how to judge weather a function is a template function...

Comment: In this case, your `auto` lamda isn't fully defined. Its only defined when the type of auto is deduced.

Comment: Thanks.So it is impossible to get a  parameter number from a generic lambda?

Comment: @haskeller Because generic lambada is a lambda with template `operator()`, when `f2` is a generic lambda, `decltype(f2)` is an illegal expression, because no argument is used.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are not in any way functions.

The compiler treats `f1` and `f2` as if they were classes with call operators.

Some lambdas have implicit conversion operators to function pointers.

[Here is a link](https://cppinsights.io/s/b7e91626) to what those two look like in cppinsights.

BTW, I **highly** recommend using [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) if you are new to C++ templates.  [Here is a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJ6ZvDRYzNE) talking about it, and [here is one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZVIRmttzW0) where he uses cppinsights to explore lambdas in depth.

I have also copied the relevant code here for explanation, and in case the link every goes away.

This is what your `f1` looks like.

```cpp
class __lambda_1_11
{
  public: 
  inline /*constexpr */ int operator()(int x) const
  {
    return x + 1;
  }

  using retType_1_11 = int (*)(int);
  inline /*constexpr */ operator retType_1_11 () const noexcept
  {
    return __invoke;
  };

  private: 
  static inline int __invoke(int x)
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
};
```

and this is what your `f2` looks like.

```cpp
class __lambda_2_11
{
  public: 
  template<class type_parameter_0_0>
  inline /*constexpr */ auto operator()(type_parameter_0_0 x) const
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
  private: 
  template<class type_parameter_0_0>
  static inline auto __invoke(type_parameter_0_0 x)
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
};
```

Note that `f1` has a non-template call operator **and** it has an implicit conversion operator to a function pointer (`int (*)(int)`).

`f2` has a template call operator and does not have an implicit conversion operator - because the call operator is a member function template.