# msvc function traits on lambda

Tags: c++11, templates, visual-c++, type-traits

I'm trying to use the function traits that was posted as the marked answer here:
[Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda)

While trying to compile it with msvc `19.16.27034` I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2825   'T': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
Error   C2510   'T': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union
Error   C2065   '()': undeclared identifier
Error   C2955   'function_traits': use of class template requires template argument list
```

On [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/y5vmYh) this works on any compiler but for some reason on my local machine I can't get this to compile because of these errors. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Adding `std::remove_reference_t`

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    struct function_traits
        : public function_traits<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>
    {
    };
```

to the declaration solves the problem.

The weird part is that even without any instantiation to the template I still get this error on the specified compiler, unless I'm adding `std::remove_reference_t`.

Anyone can explain this weird behaviour?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Paa_R3). The code from that answer compiles for me exactly as written, without any changes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik well you don't have to repeat what I already said.
I said I only experience this locally and not on godbolt, maybe someone could reproduce locally with the compiler version I've given and the code without `std::remove_reference_t`.