# Template which inherits from its own specialization - use cases? limits?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I just discovered in an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213747/751579) that a template can inherit from itself - given sufficient defined full specializations.  As seen, for example, here ([and live on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T0ZvkfejOtdo6zpH)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct Foo : public Foo<decltype(T::x)> {};

template <typename TT>
struct Foo<TT*> {
  TT* p;
};

template <typename TT>
struct Foo<TT&> {
  TT r;
};

struct Has_x {
  std::string* x;
};

int main()
{
    std::string s{"I'm 's'"};
    Foo<Has_x> foo_has_x;
    foo_has_x.p = &s;

    std::cout << typeid(foo_has_x).name() << " - " << *foo_has_x.p << std::endl;
}
```

(Example works for C++11 and on.)

I had no idea that was possible.  It's kind of an twisted cousin of CRTP.  But anyway, now I'm wondering how it can be used - or has been used.

Obviously, the [answer linked above (by Columbo)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213747/751579) was a very nice use case: Be able to find the argument types and return types of a (non-generic) functor or lambda. (And it does that by providing specializations suitable for function signatures, and inheriting using the `decltype` of its type parameter's `operator()`.)

But what else can it be/has it been used for?  Perhaps something *not* `decltype`-of-a-member-ish?

Also, what limitations are associated with this?  I don't see, for example, how to deal (nicely, meaning by providing defaults) with any case that is *not* fully specialized.  Your full specializations need to cover all cases.  *Can* you provide a default case?  Are there other limitations to be aware of?

Comment: default is the primary template... You mght still have this kind of inheritance somewhere else as `template <typename T>
struct Bar; template <typename T>
struct Bar<T*> : Bar<T>{};`.

Comment: *"that is not fully specialized"*, your snippet, as the linked code use **partial** specialization, fully specialization is for type such as `template <> struct Bar<std::vector<int>> {};`.