# Default constructed std::priority_queue with a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, constructor, c++20, priority-queue

I *mistakenly* omitted the `compare` argument when defining a `std::priority_queue`:

```cpp
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto cmp{[](int a, int b) { return a > b; }};
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq;
}
```

, and it compiled successfully *and* worked properly when I used it to implement Dijkstra's algorithm.
Then I realized that I passed only the type information of `cmp` when constructing `pq`.

However, the code compiles only if `--std=c++20` flag is used.
I skimmed the [priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) reference on `cppreference.com` but couldn't find any notice about a change that occurred since C++20.

I used the following version of `g++`:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
```

Is this an intended behavior since C++20, and if so, what has affected this change?

Comment: Since C++20, lambda is default constructible.

Comment: *capture-less lambdas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change happened on [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

> If no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default constructor. Otherwise, it has no default constructor (this includes the case when there is a capture-default, even if it does not actually capture anything). (Since C++20)

Before C++20, lambda closure types are not *DefaultConstructible*, the comparator object can't be default-constructed in the default constructor of `std::priority_queue`, then you have to pass the lambda object to the constructor of `std::priority_queue` taking comparator object.

```
constexpr auto cmp{[](int a, int b) { return a > b; }};
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

Comment: Does it mean that the specific `return a > b;`, but not, e.g., `return a <= b`, is implied from the lambda type signature itself?

Comment: @JayLee The signature doesn't matter, you can change the ordering what you want, using `return a > b;` you'll get the smallest element as the `top()`; using `return a < b;` you'll get the largest element as the `top()`.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question: How does the compiler manages to construct `cmp` itself only from `decltype(cmp)`?

Comment: For example, I can find out the argument & the return type of a lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda , and I can see that the compiler can construct `cmp` from the `(cmp)` in the expression `decltype(cmp)`. But is the body of `cmp` actually being deduced from the `decltype(cmp)` itself?

Comment: @JayLee `decltype(cmp)` gives the type of the lambda, then default-construct it as the comparator. It's just same as [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h2mr3IKHSRcgwsj5) unless the compiler generates the lambda closure type for you instead a user-defined one.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking this... Thank you!

Comment: So the compiler identifies each lambda via labeling: `main::{lambda(int, int)#1}`, `main::{lambda(int, int)#2}`, etc. Now everything is clear to me!