# Getting return type of an overloaded member function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, return-type

I am trying to determine the return type of an overloaded member function to later use that type in my function template (see the example below). Cannot figure out how to do it using C++11 templating machinery (without modifying the definitions for struct A and B in the code below). Is this doable (in C++11 in general and MSVS2013 in particular) and how?

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

struct X
{
    double f(A&);
    int* f(B&);
};

template<typename T, typename R = /*??? what X::f(T) returns ???*/>
R ff(T& arg)
{
    X x;
    R r = x.f(arg); // preferably if I can create local variables of type R here
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    A a; ff(a);
    B b; ff(b);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting the return type from an overloaded function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260561/extracting-the-return-type-from-an-overloaded-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `decltype()` for this, using `std::declval` to simulate values of the types needed to create the method call expression:

```
typename R = decltype(std::declval<X>().f(std::declval<T&>()))
```

[Here is a demo](http://ideone.com/aunpSO) that outputs the type ID of `R`; you can see that it correctly deduces `double` and `int *` for `ff(a)` and `ff(b)` respectively.

---

Side note: the entire body of your template function can be reduced to `return X().f(arg);`.

Comment: Nice answer, can you just explain your last comment? Why do we need `X::f() const`?

Comment: @vsoftco I was mistaken; they overloads don't have to be `const`. Sometimes I get confused about temporaries: since they can only be bound to `const` references I accidentally think of temporaries as `const` themselves on occasion, but they are not.

Comment: I specifically didn't use `return X().f(arg)` to exclude using an `auto` as return type on ff() (C++14) as a possible solution (which wouldn't allow to create local variables of type R and wouldn't work in MSVS2013).

Comment: @PowerGamer But you could still create local variables without having the `R` template parameter available: `auto r = x.f(arg);`. :) If you can't use C++14 features you can just say so in your question instead of writing contrived code.

Comment: I did mention that I was looking for C++11 solution in my question, as for the local variable you are correct.

Comment: How about `result_of`?

Comment: @JorenHeit That will work if you know the *exact* signature of the function to be called, and it will require an ugly cast to extract the correct pointer. And since the return type is part of the signature, you can't cast it until you've already extracted the return type -- it's a chicken and egg problem. So no, you can't use `result_of` with overloaded functions since you are required to know the answer to the question you're asking.

Comment: @cdhowie Ah right, thanks. However, this is C++11 and will still work: `template <typename T> auto ff(T&& arg) -> decltype(X().f(arg)) { ... }`

Comment: @JorenHeit That is definitely an option, though I would point out that it depends on the availability of a default constructor for `X`. In this case we know `X` needs one because of the function implementation so it works. As a *general* answer I would prefer `-> decltype(std::declval<X>().f(arg))` but for a specific one using `X()` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use C++14 auto return type deduction like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto ff(T& arg)
{
    X x;
    auto r = x.f(arg);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: The best solution - but for the future. At the moment MSVS2013 does not support this feature and the support will be added only in MSVS2015 which is not released yet.

Comment: @PowerGamer For some users the future is already here (e.g. if they use clang, this works since December 2013). Maybe some of them have the same problem and find this question this way, but do not have your constraints. It would help them, thus my answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can use the late return type:

```
template <typename T>
auto ff(T&& arg) -> decltype(std::declval<X>().f(arg))
{
    return X().f(arg);
}
```

In C++14, you can even omit the late return type and let the compiler determine everything itself, like in Baum mit Augen's answer.

**Edit:** made the late return type work for non-default constructable types `X`.